# How to parse a large malformed HTML page, in Python?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, lxml.html

I'm trying to parse a large HTML page with a malformed table markup.
There are around 7000-10000 rows in the table.
The problem is that none of the `tr`, `th`, `td` is closed. So, the markup is like this:

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<center>

    <table border = 1>
        <tr height=40><th colspan = 16><font size=4>Dummy content
        <tr><th>A
            <th>B
            <th>C
            <th>D
            <th>E
            <th>F
            <th>G


        <tr><td>A
            <td>B
            <td>C
            <td>D
            <td>E
        <tr><td>A
            <td>B
            <td>C
            <td>D
            <td>E
    .........
    .........

    </table>
    </center>
    </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

I tried `BeautifulSoup.prettify()` to fix it, but BeautifulSoup runs in to a maximum recursion depth error. Also tried with lxml, as follows:

```
from lxml import html
root = html.fromstring(htmltext)
print len(root.find('.//tr'))
```

But it returns a length of around 50, where there are actually above 7000 `tr`'s.

Is there a good way to parse the HTML and extract content for each row?

Comment: may i suggest regex?

Comment: Does the input actually look like that, or have you reformatted it? You could try something like replacing all `<tr>` with `</tr><tr>`, all `<th>` with `<\th><th>`, etc ... that would certainly reduce the amount of errors.

Comment: @omri_saadon can you suggest a simple example code.

Comment: @3-14159265358979323846264 I have only changed the content inside the tags like the A,B,C ..etc. The structure of the input is exactly the same.

Comment: @rahules what data do you need to extract? show me a specific example please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are looking for something like this.

```
import re
trs = re.findall(r'(?<=<tr>).*?(?=<tr>)', your_string, re.DOTALL)
print trs
```

this regex will return everything between two tr labels. if you want to search between two other labels, just change the first tr and the second tr to the thing you need.

i ran a little test and it worked for me, let me know if it helped you.

Comment: The search result is returning None. http://pastebin.com/24MjA3af This is a pastebin for a sample markup. And yest, I am looking for extracting things between two tr's

Comment: @rahules I edited the code, try this and let me know please

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest trying the HTMLParser module. I just wrote some code that uses it, and I couldn't test my "except HTMLParser.HTMLParseError" block because I couldn't devise input that would make the parser fail!